# Why do updates on "contentOffset" of a UIScrollView make no effect?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which is scrollable both vertically and horizontally. This view is filled with lots of buttons, each of them with its own width (but all with the same height).

When one of these buttons gets tapped, a slider-like interface is brought to life. If this interface goes over the selected button, the whole scroll view must be scrolled so that the button becomes visible once again.

My app behaves as expected when the Y coordinate of the scroll view's content offset is set to a limit (this limit can be 0 or the view's height). But if the content offset is located in an intermediate vertical position, the scrolling just doesn't seem to happen.

At first, I tried the following approach:

```
CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x + horizontalVar, 
                                self.scrollView.contentOffset.y); 

[self.scrollView setContentOffset: newOffset animated: YES];
```

Which didn't work, as I mentioned.

Then, I tried to manually animate the view, using its property setter:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3 animations: ^{
   CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x +  horizontalVar, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y);

   self.scrollView.contentOffset = newOffset;
}];
```

That approach produced the following result: if the scroll view is in an intermediate vertical position when one of its buttons gets tapped, the content offset update causes a visual change, but the view almost immediately returns to its original state.

I have no other clues on the subject. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you didn't set the ContentSize of your scrollView.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I had a delegate associated with scrolling events. Those methods were messing with my scrolling logic. Thank you very much for your help!